# problems using __next__ method in python

Tags: python-2.6

I have just started learning python and am reading about classes .

this is the code i had written for a simple iterable class :

```
class maths:
          def __init__(self,x):
             self.a=x
          def __iter__(self):
             self.b=0
             return self
          def next(self):
            if self.b <= self.a:
               self.b = self.b+1
               return self.b-1
            else:
               raise StopIteration


x=maths(5)
  for l in x:
       print l
```

for the next() method when i used the `__next__`(self):
the following error was displayed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 20, in <module>
    for l in x:
TypeError: instance has no next() method
```

Can anyone elucidate on this behaviour . i saw an example in the dive into python 3 book by Mark Pilgrim that used the `__next__` method . even the example did not run on my interpreter .
Thanks for taking your time off to help me !

Comment: Related: [there's no next() function in a yield generator in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274606/theres-no-next-function-in-a-yield-generator-in-python-3)

Answer (score 49):

You're using Python 2.x, which has used `.next()` since forever and still does so - only Python 3 renamed that method to `.__next__()`. Python 2 and 3 aren't compatible. If you're reading a 3.x book, use Python 3.x yourself, and vice versa.

For Python 2.x, you can change `__next__()` to `next()`

Comment: Updating "__next__() to next()" worked for me as my IDE PyCharm version 2018.3 uses python 2.7.15.

Comment: If you want to make sure to have both Python2 and Python3 covered in your code, write your logic in the `__next__(self)` function, and implement a `next(self)` method that only calls `self.__next__()`. That way you're covered if and when the version is switched

Comment: Actually since they are the same function you're better off simply assigning them rather than making one function call the other. ``next = __next__`` will cause it be 2and3 compatible.