# there's no next() function in a yield generator in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262184/how-to-make-a-iterable-object-like-this), I have an endless sequence using Python generators. But the same code doesn't work in Python 3 because it seems there is no `next()` function. What is the equivalent for the `next` function?

```
def updown(n):
    while True:
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
        for i in range(n - 2, 0, -1):
            yield i

uptofive = updown(6)
for i in range(20):
    print(uptofive.next())
```

Comment: Related: [problems using __next__ method in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982817/problems-using-next-method-in-python)

Comment: How does this code work? I get that it DOES work, but from what I read, "The execution of the code stops when a yield statement has been reached". (https://www.python-course.eu/python3_generators.php). So in the first `for i in range(n)`, why doesn't `yield` simply return "1"? Instead, after the first value in the range, the code continues, and yields the entire range, which to me seems to be that yield is called multiple times at once. I'm having a little trouble understanding the nuance.

Comment: The first time the `for` calls the generator object created from your function, it will run the code in your function from the beginning until it hits `yield`, then it’ll return the first value of the loop. Then, each other call will run the loop you have written in the function one more time, and return the next value, until there is no value to return.
(taken from [this tutorial](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/))

Answer (score 136, accepted):

In Python 3, use `next(uptofive)` instead of `uptofive.next()`.

The built-in `next()` function also works in Python 2.6 or greater.

Comment: Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: @KennyWorden Consistency(yyy), as explained in [PEP3114](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/) that [cfi linked in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12277528/1201863).

Answer (score 46):

In Python 3, to make syntax more consistent, the `next()` method was renamed to `__next__()`. You could use that one. This is explained in [PEP 3114](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/).

Following Greg's solution and calling the [builtin `next()` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#next) (which then tries to find an object's `__next__()` method) is recommended.

Comment: Particularly since the function is portable between versions 2 and 3, while the methods (because of the name change) aren't.