# Removing the first line of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, line

How would I remove the first line of a CSV file in python, the first few lines of my CSV file are:

```
Domain Name, ItemID, Auction Type, Time Left, Price, Bids, Domain Age, Traffic,ValuationPrice
TICKETFINE.COM,134774365,Bid,05/09/2014 08:00 AM (PDT),$100,0,0,0,$0
CREATINGMY.COM,134774390,Bid,05/09/2014 08:00 AM (PDT),$500,0,0,0,$0
WPTHEMEHELP.COM,134774444,Bid,05/09/2014 08:00 AM (PDT),$45,1,0,0,$0
APK-ZIPPY.COM,134774445,Bid,05/09/2014 08:00 AM (PDT),$10,0,0,0,$0
FAMILYBUZZMARKETING.COM,134689583,Bid,05/09/2014 08:00 AM (PDT),$90,0,0,0,$0
AMISRAGAS.COM,134689584,Bid,05/09/2014 08:00 AM (PDT),$35,0,0,0,$0
```

Comment: Or just use the shell: `sed -i '1d' csv`.

Comment: @jfs: How could this question be a duplicate of one that was asked _after_ it was?

Comment: @martineau https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/137096

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
with open("test.csv",'r') as f:
    with open("updated_test.csv",'w') as f1:
        next(f) # skip header line
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do when I want to skip reading the first line of a CSV.

All that has to be done is call the `next()` function of the CSV object, in this case - `read`, and then the pointer to the reader will be on the next line.

```
import csv

try:
    read = csv.reader(f)
    read.next()     # Skip the first 'title' row.
    for r in read:
        # Do something
finally:
    # Close files and exit cleanly
    f.close()
```

Hope this is pretty clean an simple for your purposes!

Comment: If anyone's reading this now, it's `next(read)` now

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else caught up this error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next' python
```

In Python3 a text file object doesn't have a `next()` function. 
So you can't call `f.next()`.

Instead you should use `f.readline()` as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967509/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-next-python).

Or you can use the built-in `next(f)` which @vrjr mentioned in the comment, and is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274606/theres-no-next-function-in-a-yield-generator-in-python-3).

Comment: In Python3 you can call `next(f)` instead.

Comment: @vrjr why is `next(f)` better than `f.readline()`?

Comment: I don't know that it's better, and I didn't claim that. But you said that py3 file line objects dont have a next method, which is true, but you didn't mention that they added the next function and that it could be used instead.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my answer to include that. Thanks :)

Comment: `readline` does the job

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening it and re-saving it with the same name?

Otherwise, you could read it in without reading in the first line and writing to a new file without that line.

Answer (score -1):

- [Read the file line-by-line](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)
- [Write each line to a new file, omitting the first](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)
- [replace the first file with the second](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: As an additional hint, files get read in as iterables, and you can use `next(name_of_iterable)` to get through one iteration.

Comment: @squiguy:  The `csv` module should not be needed here except in the rare case that the header row has embedded newlines that need to be parsed.