# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next' python

Tags: python

I am using python 3.3.3. I am doing the tutorial from tutorialspoint.com. I am unable to understand what this error is.

Here is my code:

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "w")
print ("Name of the file: ", fo.name)

# Assuming file has following 5 lines
# This is 1st line
# This is 2nd line
# This is 3rd line
# This is 4th line
# This is 5th line

seq = ["This is 6th line\n", "This is 7th line"]
# Write sequence of lines at the end of the file.
fo.seek(0, 2)
line = fo.writelines( seq )

# Now read complete file from beginning.
fo.seek(0,0)
for index in range(7):
 #  line = fo.next()
   print ("Line No %d - %s" % (index, line)+"\n")

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

Error:

```
Name of the file:  foo.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/python/s/fyp/filewrite.py", line 19, in <module>
    line = fo.next()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: Do you actually have `# line = fo.next()` commented out in your code?

Comment: yes when i dont comment this it gave me this error

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm here is the link i am trying

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's two reasons you're running into issues here. The first is that you've created `fo` in write-only mode. You need a file object that can read and write. You can also use the `with` keyword to automatically destruct a file object after you're done with it, rather than having to worry about closing it manually:

```
# the plus sign means "and write also"
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as fo:
    # do write operations here
    # do read operations here
```

The second is that (like the error you've pasted very strongly suggests) the file object `fo`, a text file object, doesn't have a `next` method. You're using an tutorial written for Python 2.x, but you're using Python 3.x. This isn't going to go well for you. (I believe `next` was/maybe is valid in Python 2.x, but it is not in 3.x.) Rather, what's most analogous to `next` in Python 3.x is `readline`, like so:

```
for index in range(7):
    line = fo.readline()
    print("Line No %d - %s % (index, line) + "\n")
```

Note that this will only work if the file has at least 7 lines. Otherwise, you'll encounter an exception. A safer, and simpler way of iterating through a text file is with a for loop:

```
index = 0
for line in file:
    print("Line No %d - %s % (index, line) + "\n")
    index += 1
```

Or, if you wanted to get a little more pythonic, you could use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
for index, line in enumerate(file):
    print("Line No %d - %s % (index, line) + "\n")
```

Comment: after replacing fo.next() error is : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/python/s/fyp/filewrite.py", line 20, in <module>
    line = fo.readline()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: @user3185892 As that error suggests, you haven't opened a readable file object. See my update.

Answer (score 5):

In Addition to the file mode issue `"r+"` which others have mentioned, the error message quoted by the OP happens because the `f.next()` method is no longer available in Python 3.x. It appears to have been replaced by the built in function 'next()' (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) which calls the `.__next__()` method of an iterator.

You could add the underscores to the method in your code `line = fo.__next__()`- but it is probably best to use the built in function: `line = next(fo)`

I know this is an old question - but I felt it important to include this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are not following the tutorial correctly. You have opened the file **Write only** `open("foo.txt", "w")`

The action `line = fo.next()` is a read, so obviously it will crash.
So fix it by opening as write **and** read: `fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")`

But that's only for **Python 2.7**, you should probably use **next** or fix the iteration via an other way. Check @furkle's answer.

The tutorial is probably also incorrect, see explanation of the modes here: [python open built-in function: difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r)

Comment: Whups, I checked it, it should be r+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349781/how-to-open-read-write-or-create-a-file-with-truncation-possible

Comment: This is half-correct - as far as I can tell `next()` is not a valid command on a text file object, hence the error he gets.

Comment: No, I just tried it. Open() returns an iterable object. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next

Comment: Also if it was not the case, it would have not worked in forloops.

Comment: That's the documentation for python 2.x. Both he and I are on 3.x. For me, I can iterate through the file object, but .next() results in the same error.

Comment: For 3.x, the documenation says it's https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__. (So yes, you are right, cannot test it for 3.x here)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fo.\__next__()` or `fo.next()` in python3.x.