# How to translate this code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5 to fix --- > AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, iterator

I am using Python 3.5 but this book is teaching 2.7 (beats me why in 2016)

Learning Predictive Analytics with Python by Ashish Kumar Feb 15, 2016

```
    >>> data=open(filename,'r')
    >>> cols=data.next().strip().split(',')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
        cols=data.next().strip().split(',')
    AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
    >>>
```

I have read this 
[AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next' python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967509/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-next-python)
and I still don't know how to get it to work in Python 3.5 GUI shell.

So far, I understand for Python 3.5 I have to use `.__next__`; for Python 2.7  `.next`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`next()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on iterators:

```
cols = next(data).strip().split(',')
```

This is compatible across Python versions.

You could indeed swap `.next()` for `.__next__()`, but it is better to use the standard function here, just as you'd use `len(obj)` instead of calling `obj.__len__()`. Double-underscore methods are *hooks* used by Python, your code should use the standard APIs that may or may not call those hooks. This is especially true here, where the hook name changed.

Comment: In addition, the api calls are guaranteed to work even if the underlying methods (like `__next__()`) are changed.

Comment: Thanks a million. It works . Martin. Don't you ever sleep ? :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just a question; when does one needs to use these *hook methods* ?

Comment: @IronFist: when you are trying to use *just* the hook effect; so when you are implementing `__ne__` you can call `self.__eq__` to avoid having Python test the inverse too if your own `__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`. Or when you want to avoid infinite recursion in `__getattribute__` you'd use `super().__getattribute__`, etc. So you call the hook method directly when you must, otherwise use the standard path.