# python - Django AttributeError when try to migrate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I try to run `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate` or even `python manage.py createsuperuse` i caught a error `AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'encoding'`. I think this is a problem with `manage.py` script because i was try migrate with different db and every time i was have a same problem.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "webapp\manage.py", line 10, in <modu
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  utility.execute()
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  username = self.get_input_data(self.username_field, input_msg, default_usern
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages
  raw_value = input(message)
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\codecs.py", l
  return getattr(self.stream, name)
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to run python 2 code on python 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967509/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-next-python#26967622

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I think it's unlikely. I use pycharm and i have only py3 interpretator (3.5.1) so all package that I'm install a py3 version. And if i wrote code in python2 version IDE was highlight it.