# Python - How to read a specific line in a text file?

Tags: python, text, readline

I have a huge text file (12GB). The lines are tab delimited and the first column contains an ID. For each ID I want to do something. Therefore, my plan is to go start with the first line, go through the first column line by line until the next ID is reached.

```
start_line = b
num_lines = 377763316

while b < num_lines:
  plasmid1 = linecache.getline("Result.txt", b-1)
  plasmid1 = plasmid1.strip("\n")
  plasmid1 = plasmid1.split("\t")

  plasmid2 = linecache.getline("Result.txt", b)
  plasmid2 = plasmid2.strip("\n")
  plasmid2 = plasmid2.split("\t")


    if not str(plasmid1[0]) == str(plasmid2[0]):
      end_line = b
      #do something
```

The code works, but the problem is that linecache seems to reload the txt-file every time. The code would run several years if I don't increase the performance.

I appreciate your help if you have a good idea how to solve the issue or know an alternative approach!

Thanks,
Philipp

Comment: Lines are tab- delimited? Sounds like columns to me?

Comment: Please, show all the code. What is `linecache`

Comment: @eguaio: https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html

Comment: `linecache` is not designed for this.  From the source code:  "*Cache lines from Python source files*".  Yes, from looking at the source code `linecache` does reopen the file each time.  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/linecache.py

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file just once, and iterate over the lines.

```
with open('Result.txt', 'r') as f:
    aline = f.next()
    currentid = aline.split('\t', 1)[0]
    for nextline in f:
        nextid = nextline.split('\t', 1)[0]
        if nextid != currentid:
            #do stuff
            currentid = nextid
```

You get the idea, just use plain python.
Only one line is read in each iteration. The extra `1` argument in the split will split only to the first tab, encreasing performance. You will not get better performance with any specialized library. Only a plain C language implementation could beat this approach.

If you get the `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has`, it is probably because you are using Python 3.X (see question [io-textiowrapper-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967509/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-next-python)). Try this version instead:

```
with open('Result.txt', 'r') as f:
    aline = f.readline()
    currentid = aline.split('\t', 1)[0]
    while aline != '':
        aline = f.readline()
        nextid = aline.split('\t', 1)[0]
        if nextid != currentid:
            #do stuff
            currentid = nextid
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

I receive following error: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

Any ideas?

Comment: It was  a python 2 vs 3 incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think [numpy.loadtxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) is the way to go. Also it would be nice to pass `usecols` argument to specify which columns you actually need from the file. Numpy package is solid library written with high performance in mind.

After calling `loadtxt()` you will get [ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools:

```
from itertools import takewhile

class EqualityChecker(object):
   def __init__(self, id):
       self.id = id

   def __call__(self, current_line):
       result = False
       current_id = current_line.split('\t')[0]

       if self.id == current_id:
           result = True

       return result


with open('hugefile.txt', 'r') as f:
   for id in ids:
       checker = EqualityChecker(id)
       for line in takewhile(checker, f.xreadlines()):
           do_stuff(line)
```

In outer loop `id` can actually be obtain from the first line with an id non-matching previous value.