# Python, call column values from a file and interpolate the values?

Tags: python

```
Iteration, $X, $Y
1,0.581261625,0.010561718
2,0.470764982,0.01282931
3,0.44202262,0.011346878
4,0.447475587,0.011324991
```

I have this file in this form, out of 500 values I put the first five. For every $X and $Y at the same iteration there is Z that will be calculated from the following code from an old X and Y.

My following code is to call the file and to find the equivalent Z for each $X and $Y that is already provided in the code.

```
import sys
from math import log
import datetime
import re
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


##interpolation data for Z 
xx = 0.15, 0.33, 0.35, 0.5, 0.67, 0.8
yy = 0.01, 0.05, 0.08, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2
zz = 0.75, 0.81, 0.83, 1.00, 0.92, 0.91, 

# Read parameter file
parametersAndValues = {}
parameterFile = open('ParameterValues') #open(os.environ['RAVEN_PARAMETERFILE'])

try:
    for line in parameterFile:
        parametersAndValues[line.split()[0]] = ((float(line.split()[1])))
finally:
    parameterFile.close()

X = parametersAndValues.get('$X')
Y = parametersAndValues.get('$Y')


for parameter in parametersAndValues:
    ( parameter + ' = ' + str(parametersAndValues.get(parameter)))
```

This part of the code is to interpolate the values of X and Y to find Z

```
##interpolation data for TLMIXPAR
tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)    
def givemeomega(X,Y):
        result = interpolate.bisplev(X,Y,tck)
        return '{:.5f}'.format(min(1.0, result))
```

The error code I keep getting is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$X,'`, so I am not able to call the value properly neither find the proper Z for $X and $Y

I appreciate all the help you can offer

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about the header when you read your file
This is how I would read the file

```
X, Y = [], []
with open('ParameterValues', 'r') as parameterFile:
    header = parameterFile.readline()
    for line in parameterFile:
        items = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]
        X.append(items[1])
        Y.append(items[2])
```

_

```
print X
# [0.581261625, 0.470764982, 0.44202262, 0.447475587]

print Y
# [0.010561718, 0.01282931, 0.011346878, 0.011324991]
```

And then do your interpolation which I don't really understand how is supposed to work
(This is an entirely separate issue)

```
Z = givemeomege(X,Y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I got this error  'header = parameterFile.next()'
'AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'',

Comment: Are you in python 2 or 3? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967509/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-next-python) answer to your error seems to indicate .next() doesn't work in this instance for python 3 (but does for python 2). Try .readline() instead of .next(), or add a 'r' to your open command to indicate you are reading the file

Comment: Exactly that what I am trying to do 'df['Z'] = givemeomega(df['$X'], df['$Y'])' for each line but I have three columns and multiple lines, but Pandas is not installed and i got error every time that I install pandas through pip, is there another way to do it without Pandas

Comment: I am on python 3

Comment: Updated answer to not use pandas (just return an array or something with your function now). Your issue now is not with pandas, but with the interpolation. I can't help you with this, I have no experience with that tool.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help