# Getting next item from generator fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

There is a code segment. running the program gets the following error

```
epoch, step, d_train_feed_dict, g_train_feed_dict = inf_data_gen.next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

The corresponding code segment is listed as follows. What can be the reason underlying it?

```
inf_data_gen = self.inf_get_next_batch(config)

def inf_get_next_batch(self, config):
        """Loop through batches for infinite epoches.
        """
        if config.dataset == 'mnist':
            num_batches = min(len(self.data_X), config.train_size) // config.batch_size
        else:
            self.data = glob(os.path.join("./data", config.dataset, self.input_fname_pattern))
            num_batches = min(len(self.data), config.train_size) // config.batch_size

        epoch = 0
        while True:
            epoch += 1
            for (step, d_train_feed_dict, g_train_feed_dict) in \
                    self.get_next_batch_one_epoch(num_batches, config):
                yield epoch, step, d_train_feed_dict, g_train_feed_dict
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is generator.next() visible in python 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073396/is-generator-next-visible-in-python-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
next(inf_data_gen)
```

Rather than:

```
inf_data_gen.next()
```

Python 3 did away with `.next()`, renaming it as `.__next__()`, but its best that you use `next(generator)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
epoch, step, d_train_feed_dict, g_train_feed_dict = next(inf_data_gen)
```

See this: [there's no next() function in a yield generator in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274606/theres-no-next-function-in-a-yield-generator-in-python-3)

In Python 3 it's required to use `next()` rather than `.next()`.

Suggested by Dillon Davis: You can also use `.__next__()`, although `.next()` is better.

Comment: It is not just _better_, it is _required_ to use `next()`.

Comment: You can use `.__next__()`- that's what it was renamed to. But its better to go with `next()`

Comment: Okay I'll add that too.